# Cross-validation using linear discriminant analysis

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

The following code performs 10-fold cross-validation using linear discriminant analysis:

```
load fisheriris
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species,10);
cp = classperf(species); % initializes the CP object

for i = 1:10
    test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
    class = classify(meas(test),meas(train),species(train));
    % updates the CP object with the current classification results
    classperf(cp,class,test)  
end

cp.CorrectRate
```

How can this be modified to use fitcdiscr instead of classify on line 7? When I try, I get an error (Wrong number of arguments). I do not know what arguments are needed or not.

Comment: Maybe look [at the documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html#bt6d86x-2_1): `fitcdiscr(meas,species)`

Comment: When I try fitcdiscr(meas,species), I get the following error: Error using classreg.learning.internal.DisallowVectorOps/subsref (line 16)
You cannot index into an object of class ClassificationDiscriminant using () indexing.

Error in classperf (line 223)
    gps = varargin{1}(:);

Answer (score 1):

fitcdiscr returns a model based on the training data with true labels. Therefore in order to obtain the predicted classes (class), we need to use the model method predict.

```
load fisheriris 
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species,10);
cp = classperf(species);
for i = 1:10
    test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
    Mdl = fitcdiscr(meas(train,:), species(train,:));
    class = Mdl.predict(meas(test,:));
    classperf(cp,class,test);
end
cp.CorrectRate
```

I tested this with the old function (classify) and the CorrectRate was the same.